# new to android dev - no layout file

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm trying to learn some android dev so I got SDK with Eclipse from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html . I've got Sony Ericsson Xperia x10 mini pro with Android 2.1 so I'm selecting API ver 7. I did everything like on the tutorial, selected "Blank activity" but when I'm trying to start my application I get an error "No launcher activity found" so nothing's doing on the phone. The second problem is that there is no layout file in project, folder res/layout is empty.
Does anyone know any solution for this? I tried it on Win xp and xubuntu 12.04 and I got the same result

Comment: Select > Android SDK Manager... and download the latest updates (including Android 2.1 level 7, assuming it is still available). If it is not available, download a higher level android version, and select that one as the target version (and only level 7 as the minSDK version).

Comment: I should warn you that Android API 7 is poorly used these days, if you want to make an app. Check https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html and see by yourself.

Comment: My 2 cents: update your mobile to **at least** Froyo (API Level 8)